# RVIZ SLAM RPLidar problem

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello friends...

I am using The RPLIDAR (Robopeak) for hector slam mapping. This lidar has a publisher node.
that link is:
http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar
and ı use its commands like this:

**$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
$ roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch ( it is started RVIZ program)**

this is working and starting publish lidar scan data.
I added LASER_SCAN and MAP tools on RVIZ display.

if ı write Laser_Scan -> Topic "/scan" and GLobal Options -> fixed frame "laser" , I can  see LIDAR data on RVİZ on rviz display.

BUT !!!!
f ı write Laser_Scan -> Topic "/scan" and GLobal Options -> fixed frame "map" , I can NOT  see LIDAR data on RVİZ on rviz display.
and I see this error:

****Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [laser]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist****

ı need to use HECTOR_SLAM Method like this video  but ı cannot started it ....

[link text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCF7P7u8pDk)

please help me...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209276/rviz-slam-rplidar-problem/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easy solution would be to manually starting a tf publisher that publishes the needed transform from the base_link (localized) to the laser scanner frame. See the example launch file below:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
```

and you should have your hector_mapping parameters like this :

```
 <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
```

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you so much

But where is the hector_mapping.launch. is it in catkin_ws->hector_slam->?

and how can I add your said tf publisher?

---

Originally posted by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) with karma: 153 on 2015-05-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [casper911ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/21126/casper911ca/) on 2015-07-23**:
Same issue here. I would like hector mapping, rather than some real time map. Many people have seemed to figured this out, but I cannot for the life of me find any precise documentation on how. I feel I'm missing something simple. I've tried MRPT but the driver is buggy and distorts the data.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-03-22**:
For people that still need help with this, you can put AlexR's line of code in your own launch file or you can run the static transform publisher from the terminal. Another option is to put the transform in your robot's transform broadcaster.

**Comment by [mtmtz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28505/mtmtz/) on 2016-11-11**:
Hello. It is solution not work in my case. I can not understand why. Can you publish launch file for starting hector_slam+rplidar ?